# Regex: Match a string up to a pattern (Which may not exist)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to parse an XML document using a regex tokenizer in Python (It's a finite set, so regex is just fine!), and I'm having trouble matching comments properly.

The format of these comments is in the form `<!--This is a comment-->` where the comment itself can contain all sorts of non-alphanumeric characters (including '-')

I want to match them in such a way that I break the comment up into the following tokens:

`<!--`

`This is a comment`

`-->`

The beginning marker is easy enough to get, and I successfully grab that with another regex, but the comment regex itself is getting too greedy and grabbing the `--` from the end marker. I want this regex to grab strings that are not necessarily enclosed in a comment as well, though, so it should also be able to take `<Tag>This is text</Tag>` and correctly return `This is text`.

This is the regex I am currently using for the text:

`[^<>]+(?!-->)`

The end result ends up being `This is a comment--`, when I just want `This is a comment` so that my other regex can grab the `-->`. This regex does work for normal tags, however, due to the existence of the '<' on the end tag and properly returns `This is text` from my previous example.

I know I must not be using negative lookahead properly. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here? I've tried `[^<>]+(?=-->)`, but then that doesn't match anything that's not a comment of this form (like the normal tags). I figured that the `(?!-->)` would stop the matching when it sees that pattern, but it doesn't seem to work like that and just continues matching until it sees the ending '>'.

Posting a segment of code for context:

```
xml_scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"  ",             lambda scanner,token:("INDENT", token)),
    (r"<[A-Za-z\d._]+(?!\/)>",  lambda scanner,token:("BEGINTAG", token)),
    (r"<\/[A-Za-z\d._]+(?!\/)>",  lambda scanner,token:("ENDTAG", token)),
    (r"<[A-Za-z\d._]+\/>",      lambda scanner,token:("INLINETAG", token)),
    (r"<!--",               lambda scanner,token:("BEGINCOMMENT", token)),
    (r"-->",                lambda scanner,token:("ENDCOMMENT", token)),
    (r"[^<>]+(?!-->)",         lambda scanner,token:("DATA", token)),
    (r"\r$", None),
])

for line in database_file:
    results, remainder = xml_scanner.scan(line)
```

This is the only thing the script is doing at the moment.

Comment: By including `--` in the result, the regular expression ensured that the match was not being followed by `-->`... `comment` on the other hand, *is* being followed by `-->` so your result is not allowed to end with that.

Comment: Ah. Is there a way to have it detect that entire pattern and not include it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that in `[^<>]+(?!-->)`, the lookahead assertion is only tried after `This is a comment--` has been matched, and of course it succeeds because there is no `-->` at the position where the regex engine has ended up.

Therefore, you have to check the lookahead at *every* position of the string. The proper idiom for this is generally:

```
(?:(?!-->).)*
```

or, in your case

```
(?:(?!-->)[^<>])*
```

This matches any number of characters except angle brackets until either `-->` occurs or the end of the string is reached.

Comment: Aha. I did not realize that the regex would work like that. Doing the lookahead first seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: How does this compare to using a positive lookahead (as shown in the current answer)? Is there any noticeable performance differences when doing the negative lookahead on every position?

Comment: Actually, just ran some timing tests and this method has a noticeably lower timing than the positive lookahead (and does the job cleaner). That makes no sense to me, but it looks like this is the better solution.

Comment: And what if you want to capture the stuff (in a capturing group, for the purpose of using backrefs) before the negative lookahead expression?

Comment: @2rs2ts: Just add a set of parentheses around it: `((?:(?!-->)[^<>])*)`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a **positive** lookahead, to ensure that this pattern is ahead of your match.

```
[^<>]+(?=-->)
```

If you want to make it more universal, so that it matches content of other tags too, you can use an alternation inside the lookahead assertion:

```
[^<>]+(?=-->|</)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?357de)

This regex will stop, if there is "`-->`" or "`</`" ahead.

Comment: While that definitely works on Regexr, it's not grabbing the complete text in between the tags for me. It's grabbing everything except the last character. So, for `<!--This is a comment-->`, it's grabbing `This is a commen`. Same applies for tags. Perhaps a have another bug somewhere else, though...

Comment: @Austin, then you should post your code, where you use the regex and how you retrieve the result.

Comment: I've posted the code for context.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what I did, but I seem to have fixed the bug that was occurring. Thanks!